# On which Starcraft 2 server there are more 2v2 players?

Tags: starcraft-2

There are not many people playing Starcraft 2 in the beginners league any more, at least not on the European servers. This results in the matchmaking mostly choosing pro players as opponents for me and my friend, who are bronze.

Are there more players on the Asian- or US-servers? So we are more likely to get equally skilled opponents?

Are there such statistics for the Starcraft servers, where you can see how many players are from which league?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On [this Site](http://www.rankedftw.com/stats/leagues/team-2v2/#v=2&r=-2&sx=a) you can see some player statistics.
To answer you question: **No** there aren't more players on the Asian- or US-servers in your league. EU is the best option for you.